# AngularJS - ng-model doesn't update with service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, jstree, angular-ngmodel

I'm working on an AngularJS's project, and i have some troubles with ng-model. I have ng-model on NgJsTree's tree (Angular version of jstree). I must build the list of nodes with a set of ajax's calls and after init the tree. So I thought to put my ajax's calls in a service with a promise and only when the promise was solved init the tree. The service works fine, but ng-model doesn't update.

In particular case, this is my code:

**Service**

```
.service('nodeService', function($q, $http){
    return {
        getNode: function(config, $scope){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var result_list = [];
            $.each(config.total_path, function (i, item) {
                if(config.total_path.indexOf(config.total_path[i]) == config.total_path.indexOf(config.total_path[config.total_path.length-1])){
                    $scope.id_model = String(config.total_path[i]).split("model_tree_")[1];
                    var url = 'localhost/url1';
                }else{
                    var url = 'localhost/url2';
                }

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    async: false,
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    for(var j=0;j<response.data.length;j++){
                        result_list.push({
                            "state": "opened",
                            "text": response.data[j].data.title,
                            "map": response.data[j].attr.map,
                            "b_view_page": response.data[j].attr.b_view_page,
                            "parent": config.total_path[i],
                            "rel": response.data[j].attr.rel,
                            "id": response.data[j].attr.id,
                            "icon": response.data[j].icon
                        });
                    }
                    if(i+1 == config.total_path.length){
                        deferred.resolve(result_list);
                    }
                });
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
```

**How call service**

```
var myDataPromise = nodeService.getNode(config, $scope);
myDataPromise.then(function(result){
    config.treeData = config.treeData.concat(result);
    ... init tree ...
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="add_margin_bottom"
    js-tree="config.treeConfig"
    should-apply="config.applyModelChanges()"
    ng-model="config.treeData"
    tree= "treeInstance"
    tree-events= "select_node: config.selectedNode;loaded: config.creationNode;ready: config.openNodes">
</div>
```

My ng-model is the variable config.treeData. Am I doing something wrong?

Sorry for my trivial question but I'm an Angular beginner.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Can you please show us where you're binding `config.treeData` to the `$scope` in your controller? And maybe also some html for where you're using it?

Comment: yes, i updated the question.

Comment: I still don't see where you're actually binding `config.treeData` to `$scope`

Comment: I bind config.treeData to $scope only in HTML, is an ng-model

Comment: See my edited answer for what I think you need to change in your controller

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't pass in the `$scope` into the service.

```
var myDataPromise = nodeService.getNode(config);
myDataPromise.then(function(result){
    config.treeData = config.treeData.concat(result);
    // Or whatever you want to do...
}
```

Also, change `config.treeData = config.treeData.concat(result);` to 
`$scope.config.treeData = config.treeData.concat(result);`

And by looking at your htlm, it looks like you need to bind `config` to the scope in your controller too. Since you're using `config.treeConfig` and `config.treeData` in your html, you need to make sure these objects are bound to the `$scope`, or the view will not know about them.

Comment: Thanks for replay @aup. I corrected it, but doesn't resolve

Comment: Change this `async: false` to `true`. You're using promises and waiting for the async callback with `.then()`, but you're not making an async call

Comment: The async refers to the single ajax's call not to the service.

Comment: Still though, doing `async: false` will freeze your browser during the requests, no?

Comment: Nope, the service works fine, i check the value of varibale and is correct